# CURL performance issues when source has a long processing time

Tags: php, curl, php-5.3

I'm using CURL to get some information from a remote server, it takes in average 15 to 20 seconds for the remote server to generate the response, and then it's about 5MB to 10MB.

The problem is that CURL takes forever to retrieve the response.

Is there any way to improve CURL performance?

Right now the solution that I've found is to have the server return a new URL to a static generated file, and then download that file. I'd like to be able to do it in only one request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Download the file via CURL via a cron job and store it locally. That way it doesn't matter how long it takes.
2. If the server can return a new URL to the statically generated content, use it. Probably via a Location: header, which will tell your script where to fetch it from.
3. Speed up the remote server somehow

Comment: 1 - Can't do via CRON because results must be shown in screen almost instantly (in 30 seconds or les)
2 - Probably to use header location is the best bet, I'll try that
3 - As I said in a another comment, the remote server speed is OK, it's querying a webservice an the response takes that time.

Comment: @Pablius: do you mean that the information must be always up to date or the webpage must display in under 30 seconds? If it's the latter it doesn't matter how long or often the cron job updates, saving it locally means the webpage can read it (nearly) instantly.

Comment: @Ryan Information must always be up to date, and is valid only for five minutes aprox.

Comment: Ok, if it's valid for about 5 minutes, update every 2 via cron. Or even update every 1 minute. Considering how long it takes to download the information every 1 minute is nearly up to date.

Answer (score 0):

What? You are saying that server takes 15-20 seconds to generate response and Curl is taking a lot time?

I don't want to blow your mind, but if you get that server to reply faster Curl will retrieve response faster.

Comment: It's a response generated by querying a webservice, that's why it takes that long and I can't do anything about it :)

Comment: Yes, but this is why Curl takes a long time... if anything ping the server first with quick fake request to let it start to generate/cache response then do curl request in 15 minutes.

Comment: I'm going to try @Ryan suggestion of using a header location to re-request the page. I can't cache results for that long (they are only valid for 5 minutes or less) and even if I could, I must show them on-screen right after the request is made (up to 30 seconds is acceptable). BTW requests are always different so it's unpredictable what the user will ask for to do it preemptively

Comment: So why not have server ping you back once request is processed so you can re-request data within that 5 minute frame

Comment: Because I have to show results on screen in less than 30 seconds

Comment: Run it in background and notify user when request is done, this is not  healthy UX.